# por que no funciona esta petición de jquery + ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

como menciono en el titulo tengo este pequeño script que valida si el usuario existe en la db pero no se que estoy haciendo mal! no recibo ningun error pero tampoco muestra la respuesta (los echo de php)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').on('blur', function(){
        $('#icon').html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>').fadeOut(1000);

        var username=$('#username').val();
        var dataString='user='+username;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'valid.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response){
                $('#icon').fadeIn(1000).html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

este es el código php que estoy usando

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);

        $sqlCmd = "SELECT log FORM unt WHERE login='".$user."'";
        if(mysqli_query($link,$sqlCmd)){
            $r = $mysqli_num_rows($sqlCmd);
            if($r > 0){echo 'ocupado';}
            else{echo'disponible';}
        }
    }else{echo 'error';}
?>
```

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia, a tu código PHP le faltan controles. Por ejemplo si la consulta falla tu código se queda mudo, no dice nada al respecto. Prueba a escribir el script así, se recoge todo en una variable `$msg` y se imprime al final. Ahí no escapa ninguna eventualidad:

Comment: `<?php
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST)){
 $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
 $sqlCmd = "SELECT log FORM unt WHERE login='".$user."'";
 if(mysqli_query($link,$sqlCmd)){
  $r = $mysqli_num_rows($sqlCmd);
  if($r > 0){
   $msg='ocupado';
  }
  else{
   $msg='disponible';
  }
 }else{
  $msg='Error en la consulta: '.mysqli_error($link);
 }
}else{
 $msg='error: no se recibió POST para user';
}
echo $msg;
?>` Y, considera usar consultas preparadas para dar seguridad a tu código, el cual tal como está es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ver si el ajax te está dando un error puedes usar el `.fail()` que te permite sacar el error:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'valid.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response){
         $('#icon').fadeIn(1000).html(response);
    }
}).fail(function(error){ console.log(error); });
```

Esto te permitirá ver si hay algún error interno.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que el `data:` del ajax tiene que pasar un objeto, por lo que tienes que cambiar el `dataString` a objeto:

```
var dataString={ user: username };
```

Por último te recomiendo comprobar la ruta del archivo `valid.php` ya que ahí dices que el archivo `JS` y el `PHP` están en la misma carpeta. De no ser así tendrías que cambiar la url.